# Ionic и глобальные переменный

Tags: angularjs, ionic, ionicframework, ionic3

Подскажите, как создать глобальную переменную, которую смогу использовать в любом месте мобильного приложения?

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете создать файл, например с названием global.ts и расположить его рядом с app.module
Файл:

```
export const Global = {
foo: "bar"
}
```

Далее в нужном компоненте вы импортируете данный файл и задаете локальную переменную.

```
import {Global} from "path-to-file";
```

Далее, выше конструктора в компоненте задаете переменную:

```
global = Global;
```

Теперь вы можете внутри компонента обращаться к свойствам в Global

```
console.log(global.foo) // Выведет bar
```

В HTML:

```
<div>{{global.foo}}</div>
```